# Сторонняя директория с исходниками

Tags: препроцессор, android, java, resources, package

Есть несколько версий одной программы, которые отличаются только ресурсами(изображения, strings.xml) и естественно пакеджем. Все файлы в директории SRC идентичы. Собрал все файлы сорцов во внешней папке SRC, и подключил ее ко все проектам. Все бы хорошо, но во многих файлах используется R.java, который генерируется по пути gen/<package of app>/R.java.

Раньше решал такую проблему с использованием ant + antenna (препроцессинг). 
Хотел спросить, есть ли альтернативные способы решения такой проблемы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

красивый способ получается с использованием gradle (элемент flavors)